# Como habilitar opção de colar imagem no chrome?

Tags: ckeditor

eu estou com um probleminha aqui, talvez meio besta e preciso de uma ideia de vocês

Utilizo aquele editor CKEDITOR em um sistema de controle meu, e onde vou fazer as edições eu preciso tirar um print de uma imagem e já colar ela no editor sem que eu precise salvar a imagem, já fiz o teste e no google chrome não dá certo, no Mozilla Firefox a coisa flui normalmente, tem algo que eu possa fazer no Google Chrome para que isso de certo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que o plugin http://ckeditor.com/addon/imagepaste deve resolver, todavia ele é bem desatualizado, desde 2013 sem atualizações

Para instalar extraia o conteudo e coloque na pasta plugins para ficar desta forma:

```
ckeditor\
    ...
    images\
    lang\
    plugins\
        ...
        imagepaste\
            plugin.js
            docs\
                install.html
        ...
    skins\
    themes\
```

No `config.js` adicione:

```
config.extraPlugins='imagepaste';
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado.